# How do I make my animation go slower?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a game with HTML5. With javascript, I'm making my character move when the user presses the arrow keys. The animation is made up of 6 sprites.

The thing is when I hold down the right arrow key (for example), my character moves smoothly but seems to be moving too fast. It's like a little bird flapping his wings so rapidly that you can barely see the appearance of the character.

Code snippet:

```
if (38 in keysDown) { // Player holding up
        if (character.y>=0)
        {
        character.y -= character.speed * modifier;
        position++;
        if(position > NUM_POSITION) 
                position = 0; 
        }
    }
```

My code implements the requestAnimationFrame and modifier (to manipulate the speed of the character per second).

I wonder how other people deal with a character that seems to be walking so fast. I'm not saying that the character TRAVELS across the page fast because I can just reduce the speed. I'm saying the character switches sprites so rapidly that you can barely see him unless you stop moving.

Comment: Use a `setTimeout` instead?

Comment: How can we help with your animation code if you don't provide it?

Answer (score 0):

I found this example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2yfsxumx/). In that case if you increase the `x` variable, the animation become faster.

I hope I could be a good example for your problem.

```
var elem=document.getElementById("toChange"); var x=0;

function moreVisible() {
    if(x==1)clearInterval(t);
    x+=0.05;
    elem.style.opacity=x;
    elem.style.filter="alpha(opacity="+(x*100)+")"; }

var t=setInterval(moreVisible,25);
```